# Machine learning classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have been trying to find a good summary for the usage of popular classifiers, kind of like rules of thumb for when to use which classifier. For example, if there are lots of features, if there are millions of samples, if there are streaming samples coming in, etc., which classifier would be better suited in which scenarios?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad to be answerable. Different classifiers will perform best depending on the true data generating process, how the classifier will be used, etc. Your best bet is to read some books that discuss this. *The Elements of Statistical Learning* is probably a good place to start.

Comment: @gung I agree that the question is too broad, but Marc Claesen pointed the cheat sheet that summarizes the topic in a very convenient way so it convinced me to retract my close vote.

Comment: @Tim I agree the answer by Marc Claesen provides a convenient summary, however I think the question itself is too broad. I don't a single answer can address it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rules of thumb can only get you so far, but [scikit-learn's cheat sheet](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/) is quite helpful for basic guidance. [Here](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.be/2013/01/machine-learning-cheat-sheet-for-scikit.html)'s a blog post by the creator of said diagram.

[image]

Comment: @AD.Net yes, that is a nice cheat sheet but don't forget that the reality is more complicated than that. So better use it as an aid but start with a statistics handbook (e.g. the one pointed out by *gung* in his comment).

Comment: As an ANN fanboy I'd like to point out that this sheet contains nothing about ANNs/Deep Learning so it really is incomplete (as the blog post itself admits)

Comment: @runDOSrun yep, it is definitely incomplete. Other common approaches like Naive Bayes, decision trees and even logistic regression are omitted.

Comment: @AD.Net, if this diagram sufficiently resolves your question, please consider accepting it. If what you need is more than this, your question is probably too broad to be answerable.